# The probability of getting at least one double six in a ten throws of a pair of fair dice.

Tags: probability

I calculated the probability of obtaining a double six as 1/36 and not obtaining it as 35/36
But to get at least one double six, I multiplied the probability by power 10. Yet I can't seem to arrive at the answer. What am I doing wrong please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you remember that you have to take the complement?  In other words, if $A$ is the event that there is at least one double-six observed in ten throws, and $B$ is the event that there are no double-sixes observed in ten throws, then $$\Pr[A] = 1 - \Pr[B].$$  Since $$\Pr[B] = \left(\frac{35}{36}\right)^{10},$$ the answer is not this number, but $1$ minus this number.

Comment: Therefore it suffices to say that the probability of getting at least one double six is as a result of not getting any double six